# when open app i get data from MYSQL in reclerview but after close app and back to open i get empty page

Tags: android, mysql, sharedpreferences, android-volley, network-connection

I build app that retrieve data from MySQL database Using Volley and show it in recycler view the problem that when I login an d open app all thing ids fine and I can get data but if I closed app (work in background )and back to open app I can see the recycler View is empty

I tried to logout and login again I get the retrieve data and same issue if set app in background or closed it